# NullPointerException on Display Data(from an intent) in a TextView

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, nullpointerexception, textview

I am going to build app which shows the bus connection.
My problem is that I get a nullpointer exception when I am putting a string into an intent and want to display this String in a TextView.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        HaltestelleName = intent.getStringExtra("HaltestelleName");
        final String Zeit = intent.getStringExtra("Zeit");

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == requestCode)
        {


            if(rgStatus.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdAbfahrt)
            {
                txtHaltestelleStart.setText("HTL Neufelden");
                txtHaltestelleZiel.setText(HaltestelleName);
            }
            else
            {
                txtHaltestelleStart.setText(HaltestelleName);
                txtHaltestelleZiel.setText("HTL Neufelden");
            }
        }
        txtZeit.setText(Zeit);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

Here is my Subactivity Code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

       Intent haltestelle = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                                       PlanActivity.class);
       String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
       haltestelle.putExtra("HaltestelleName", item);

       setResult(RESULT_OK,haltestelle);
       finish();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat...

Comment: Where do you set extraText for Zeit?

Comment: Where you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: In order for us to help you, can you post the logcat output please ?

Comment: You should check if Zeit is null before set it as text for txtZeit.

Comment: Please post the logcat, so that we can rectify your errors. And also mention the line at which you are getting `NPE`...

Answer (score 0):

hi please add the line

```
 haltestelle.putExtra("Zeit", "yours passed value");
```

just below

```
haltestelle.putExtra("HaltestelleName", item);
```

Comment: i cant understand why?

Answer (score 0):

> Hi You didn't pass any value in your subactivity in "Zeit" name just pass some value from your sub activity to avoid null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        HaltestelleName = intent.getStringExtra("HaltestelleName");
        final String Zeit;

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == requestCode)
        {


            if(rgStatus.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdAbfahrt)
            {
                txtHaltestelleStart.setText("HTL Neufelden");
                txtHaltestelleZiel.setText(HaltestelleName);
            }
            else
            {
                txtHaltestelleStart.setText(HaltestelleName);
                txtHaltestelleZiel.setText("HTL Neufelden");
            }
        }
        if (!getIntent().hasExtra("HaltestelleName")) {
     Zeit = intent.getStringExtra("Zeit");
    txtZeit.setText(Zeit);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple logic behind sending the data across two activities:

**Activity A:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity B:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Yeah I did this but is it posible to get two results, because i have two Activities for result and just one onActivityResult in my main